# How to make column resizable

Tags: magento2, admin, adminhtml, grid, resize

I want to make my columns in admin resizable.

This is not working.

```
<resizeEnabled>true</resizeEnabled>
<resizeDefaultWidth>150</resizeDefaultWidth>

<column name="title">
     <settings>
          <filter>text</filter>
              <editor>
                  <validation>
                      <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                   </validation>
                   <editorType>text</editorType>
               </editor>
               <label translate="true">Title</label>
               <resizeEnabled>true</resizeEnabled>
               <resizeDefaultWidth>150</resizeDefaultWidth>
      </settings>
</column>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<column name="title" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Title">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">150</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <filter>text</filter>
        <editor>
            <validation>
                <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
            </validation>
            <editorType>text</editorType>
        </editor>
        <label translate="true">Title</label>
    </settings>
</column>
```